# How do I track changes made to systems via knife in chef?

Tags: chef-infra

I'd like to be able to audit and track changes to node managed by chef.  Ideally I'd like to see if/when a change was made to a node to be able to correlate changes with incidents.

Is there any built-in functionality in chef that allows generation of this sort of thing?  Or, perhaps, an add-on to let me add in this sort of logging/auditing?

Answer (score 5):

jtimberman's demo handler at https://jtimberman.posterous.com/a-simple-report-handler shows how to access the specific resources that were updated in during a chef-client run.  You could write a handler that sends off email, or a HTTP post, or whatever notification mechanism you like.

Chef handlers can be distributed and installed as part of your node's run_list.  I have a couple of handlers installed by modifing /etc/chef/client.rb, but apparently there is a chef_handler cookbook in the Community cookbooks, see https://github.com/opscode/cookbooks/blob/master/chef_handler/README.md.  This can supposedly configure handlers without having to muck around with templates.

Comment: All broken links. Any specific details/examples/quotes about how to make/use a handler?

Answer (score 1):

you can change the log level and location in the client.rb file.

Chef includes a resource for writing events to the log from your recipes.

http://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Chef+Configuration+Settings#ChefConfigurationSettings-logoutput

http://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Resources#Resources-Log

Answer (score 0):

You can add a custom report handler that will loop through all of the resources that were updated during the chef-solo or chef-client run, record them, and possibly email them to a sysadmin.

Comment: I was hoping there would be a config option I could add to client.rb to log which cookbooks/recipes were run to syslog or a chef-specific file.  Being able to configure this somewhere centrally would be the hope.

Comment: @DocX did you ever find a good solution for this?  I'm looking for exactly what you were seeking here.

Comment: @Winfield, I have not found a good solution.  While I continue to look for something, it is lower priority than actual operations.  If I do find/develop something to do this, I'll post it here.